# Rails 2 rendering view from nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

So i'm having problems rendering a view from a nested resource. Using rails 2.2.2 (I know, I know, ...)

**routes.rb**

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :user
end
```

**controllers/admin/user_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::UserController < AdminController

def index
  @users = User.all
end
...
```

**views/admin/user/index.erb**

```
This is the index.
```

I'm just keeping things simple ...

No errors are thrown. I expected to get a page with "This is the index." but instead i'm getting:

```
��-![��,V���T�̼�� =���
```

Any ideas ? Any help would be much appreciated.

**--- UPDATE ---**

Just found out the problem... Compress action in ApplicationController that was not working like it should.

Thanks to everyone! :)

Comment: hope `views/admin/user/index.rb` and not `index.html.erb` is a typo

Comment: @RaviMariya indeed, typing mistake here :) 
Anyway, I found the problem. Just edited my question. Thanks.